# overflow-x not working as expected

Tags: css

I have html like:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left" class="some">
</div>
</div>
```

And css like this:

```
.some{
overflow-y:auto;  
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

But the scroll bar **appears** in x-direction **also**.

Comment: this code seems fine.. can you share your code demo.. jsfiddle

Comment: You haven't defined a `width`, so at which point should the browser decide that it's an overflow?

Comment: I made some tests. This code is working fine, but maybe is something that override your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/p0qhtgzm/

It seem to me that this scroll bar is appearing due to the width, max-width or min-width property of any of the parent element of `<div id="left" class="some">` you can easily fix this issue either by inspecting and overriding that width property or by changing your css as follows:

```
.some{
overflow-y:auto;  
overflow-x:hidden;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.some{
 overflow-y:auto;  
 overflow-x:hidden;
 width : 40%;
}
```

Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to define min-height on the main div

```
#content{
width:300px;
height:70px;
min-height:200px;
}

.left{float:left;}

.some{
overflow-y:auto;  
overflow-x:hidden;
height:100px;
}
```